# dynamic appointment-pricing with django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-apps, appointment

I have an appointment app that allows clients to create doctor appointments. An admin would then award the appointment to available doctors. Part of the app reads as follows:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    MEDICAL_SERVICES_CHOICES = (
        ('DN', 'Dentist'),
        ('RA', 'Radiology'),
    )
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    appointment_day = models.DateField(validators=[present_or_future_date])
    appointment_time = models.TimeField()
    service_needed = MultiSelectField(choices=MEDICAL_SERVICES_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

With MEDICAL_SERVICES_CHOICES, clients can choose between: radiology appointments, dentist appointments, etc..

**CHALLENGE: I need to be add a system-defined pricing attribute.**

The problem is that each appointment is created by the client & not the hospital. Furthermore, I need to establish different prices for each of the MEDICAL_SERVICES_CHOICES.

**QUESTIONS**

1. How do I automatically add a service-cost/price field on each appointment?...The prices would be attached to the MEDICAL_SERVICES_CHOICES.
2. Is there a better way to do this? (I've considered going with an e-commerce model except with services rather than products: Not sure if this would be better though!)

Comment: It might be better to make a model `MedicalService`, with a `ManyToManyField` from `Appointment` to `MedicalService`, this makes it easier to add an extra service. Each service can then define a price, and then it is easy to calculate the sum. Do prices depend on the medical practitioner (doctor)?

Comment: Yes, Prices would also vary depending on the practitioner.